# TYPO3 eventnews ext - default template change error

Tags: typo3, typoscript, tx-news

I have problem with changing template for `eventnews` month view. I already copy the template EXT:eventnews/Resources/Private/Templates/Month.html into the same directory where the files like List.html or Detail.html are saved. But on site I have error like this:

> Sorry, the requested view was not found.
>
> The technical reason is: No template was found. View could not be
>   resolved for action "month" in class
>   "GeorgRinger\News\Controller\NewsController".

But when I paste TypoScript with default template:

```
plugin.tx_news {
   view {
      templateRootPaths {
             0 = {$plugin.tx_news.view.templateRootPath}
             1 = EXT:eventnews/Resources/Private/Templates/
      }
   }
}
```

everything works fine...

Where is the problem?

Here is my configuration:

- TYPO3 7.6.16
- tx_news 6.0.0
- eventnews 2.0.1
- PHP: 7.0.7

Comment: As far as I can see the file is in EXT:eventnews/Resources/Private/Templates/News/Month.html
Be sure to replicate this exact structure.

Where did you copy that? What is the value of the constant $plugin.tx_news.view.templateRootPath?

Comment: the constant value is: templateRootPath = fileadmin/new-site/ext/news/Templates/

Answer (score 0):

**Updated**

add below typoscript in setup for change eventnew template .

```
plugin.tx_news {
   view {
      templateRootPaths.1 = fileadmin/eventnews/Templates/
   }
}
```

And After paste on this path( `fileadmin/eventnews/Templates/` ) template file.

Comment: I already have the `Month.html` template in my directory (fileadmin/new-site/ext/news/Templates/News/Month.html) but when I paste  in my TS that part of code: `templateRootPaths = fileadmin/new-site/ext/news/Templates/` i have only error on my screen

Comment: If you have add this typoscript in constant then only use **plugin.tx_news.view.templateRootPath.1** not **plugin.tx_news.view.templateRootPaths.1**

Answer (score 0):

If you want to overwrite the Template `EXT:eventnews/Resources/Private/Templates/Month.html`, you have to copy the file into a separate location (e.g. into an own extension) and *add* an additional path to templateRootPaths with a higher number than the existing paths:

```
plugin.tx_news {
   view {
      templateRootPaths {
             20 = EXT:mycustomext/Resources/Private/Templates/
      }
   }
}
```

That way typo3 is going to look into that location first, before testing the others.

Overwriting `0` and `1` might cause issues if you don't overwrite all templates.

Answer (score 0):

As Riccardo De Contardi advised, I have reproduced the exact extension structure in my "ext" directory and then overwritten the TS template.

```
plugin.tx_news {
  view {
      templateRootPaths {
         0 = {$plugin.tx_news.view.templateRootPath}
         1 = fileadmin/ext/eventnews/Resources/Private/Templates/
      }
   }
}
```

Now everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

if you have set the constant:

`plugin.tx_news.view.templateRootPath = fileadmin/new-site/ext/news/Templates/`

I would expect that if you put the file in:

`fileadmin/new-site/ext/news/Templates/News/Month.html`

Everything should work out of the box. Does this work?

Comment: It should but it doesn't... I had to create another directory on server and reproduce the exact extension structure